# Can anyone recommend sources on the standardisation of research methods in modern (20th-21st c) science?

Tags: statistics, scientific-method, resource-recommendation, psychology

I’m interested in learning more about how statistical methodology and research design has changed over the course of the 20th and 21st century. I’m particularly interested in ways in which research methodology has been standardised across subfields, to the extent that it has. It seems like 20th century statistics has had a huge (and maybe homogenising?) impact on the way that science is done, so I’m particularly interested in statistical methodology. Even more particularly, I'm interested in its impact on psychology, but information on any fields is extremely welcome. Thanks.

Comment: One most significant effect is that "design of experiments" was recognized as a serious issue, with both statistical and other aspects. This plays a role mostly in very -experimental sciences, where observations in not-entirely-controllable contexts is a major device.